# Adding functionality to UIToolbar Items in IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This is a simple question, but IB makes things so difficult sometimes.

I have drag/dropped a button onto my Toolbar in IB and I need to add functionality to it that goes beyond just navigating to a new screen.  Where and how can I implement this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "add functionality that goes beyond navigating to a new screen"? That makes it sound like you already have an IBAction linked to the button that initializes a view switch,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the button with an `IBOutlet` and `IBAction`, then you can do what you need to do in code.

[UIKit Constants Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

you only need an IBAction in your viewController, the button outlet is not really needed.

the function should look like that:

```
-(IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
```

wheras `(id)sender` references the control that initiated the control. if multiple buttons use this action, you can use the sender object to determine which one it was (might spare you from setting up multiple functions)

and add your functionality there. 
in InterfaceBuilder you can then click on your button, go to connections and choose the way you want to click the button (normally touch up inside) , drag it to your files owner and chose the IBAction you just declared.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bschultz's answer...  When you set up the `IBAction` put the things that you want the button to do within it.  The `IBOutlet` is not needed as much as the `IBAction`. Once you have it set up, go to IB, Ctrl-Click on your button and drag the little line that shows up to File's Owner. Select your `IBAction`. You're done.

Comment: Well, this is what I did but the button isn't triggering the action..Does it start the segue before the action?  Like, should I call the segue inside of the action rather than connecting the button directly via ctrl+click?  Actually yes.. that seems to be the case.